# best practice for using useEffect hook with multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am new to react. I'm developing a project to learn but I'm having trouble with the use of `useEffect` hook.

In `Dashboard component` I call a nodejs api that returns a list of users as in the example:

```
Users : [{
    "name": "john",
    "age": 30
}, ... ]
```

What I want to do is to pass the age list to an `age component` and the name list to `name component` to perform some operations, like show list and charts.

Right now I made the call inside the parent component (dashboard component) passing the separate arrays via props to the child components (age and name component).

The problem, I suppose due to the asychronous nature of react and javascript, **the child components are mounted before the end of the api call causing errors**.

I was wondering what is the best practice to use in a case like this.

- Is it ok to call the api in the parent component and then sort the data between the components? In this case how should I go about waiting for the child components to load?
- Or should I make two separate calls within each child component? Would this have performance repercussions?

**CODE EXAMPLE**

***Dashboard component***

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        //api call and update users state
        }, [])

        //process users and create array of names and ages

    return (
        <Age names={names} />
        <Name ages={ages} />
    )
```

***Name component***

```
export default function Name(props) {
        return (
            props.names.map(name => {
                <p>{name}</p>
            })
        )
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the advice and help.

Comment: Can you please show the source of your components? Calling an api in the parent, setting state with the result and distributing the data in props should not be an issue.

Comment: You should lift state to an ancestor component where it makes sense. If `Age` component doesn't care about name state and `Name` component doesn't care about age state, then it seems logical for each to maintain their own state. But it's also ok to keep the state in a parent component and pass as props. Sounds like your children components don't handle missing/incomplete data that simply hasn't been fetched yet, you should guard against this, typically with some conditional rendering. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DrewReese I think maybe this is the solution, you mean for example to show a spinner until the data is available? 

For example I pass via props the list of the age and then in the component process a chart. As long as there is no data I should show a spinner?

But when the data is returned, and I update the state of the parent component, do the child components get updated?

Comment: If the parent rerenders, then the children do too. If the passed props to the children change, the children will rerender.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @DrewReese yes my doubt is that. however I implemented conditional rendering and it seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: You could benefit from server state handling libraries like react-query or SWR or Apollo. They allow you to fetch server, get usefull statuses. React-query provides useQuery hooks that allow you to trigger data fetching in many components without duplicating queries (so you can fetch data where you need it and avoid props drilling). Here you could fetch data in parent component (user=useQuery(...)), and pass the request object to children where you read statuses (if(user.isFetching) display spinner). https://react-query.tanstack.com/

Comment: Andrea, did you still have a question/issue? Are your `age` & `name` lists *actually* just 2 properties of an object in an array of `users`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `users` appears to be a single "chunk" of state, an array containing objects with both an `age` and `name` property, then the parent component would *need* to hold the state. Make a single API/asynchronous call from the parent to update any state.

You can "map"/"filter" the state into two arrays to be passed as props to the child components. This can be done "on-the-fly" as you pass the prop. When the parent's state updates the children will be passed the latest state values.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
  //api call and update users state
}, [])

return (
  <>
    <Age names={users.map(({ name }) => name)} />
    <Name ages={users.map(({ age }) => age)} />
  </>
)
```

Each child can map their received array as per usual. `array.prototype.map` can handle an empty array without issue, so there is nothing special you need to do to handle initial/empty state (unless you want to). As long as the `users` state in the parent is a defined array, `array.map` is guaranteed to return an array.

```
export default function Name({ names }) {
  return names.length ? names.map(name => <p>{name}</p>) : "...Loading";
}
```